# Cannot find my SSID in my network list anymore

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I had a router set up with 2 different SSID, one for 2.4 (SSID: `EMT`) and another for 5.0 (SSID: `EMT-5Gzh`).

The last couple days my internet was acting up, so I finally called support and after a while, he just told me to "factory reset" the router, to see if that solved the issue. So I did.

Now, after all the setup, **my phone** is capable to connect again to `EMT-5Ghz` without any problem, not needing to change any settings. But **my PC** is not being so cooperative.

In the list of visible networks, `EMT-5Ghz` is not appearing, even though `EMT` is. I know that my card can do this, because it has been doing it for months. And I have not touched any of the configuration in my PC, so it should have re-connected automatically, when I reset the router. But the 5 Ghz SSID just does not appear.

[image]

What is going on? How could I try to fix this?

**UPDATE 1** Yes, I tried rebooting my PC

**UPDATE 2** Requested info:

```
~ 
➜ iwlist wlp5s0 freq         
wlp5s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 32 : 5.16 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 66 : 5.33 GHz
          Channel 68 : 5.34 GHz
          Channel 96 : 5.48 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
```

Comment: Reboot the PC. Report back.

Comment: Already did it. It didn't solve anything.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwlist wlan0 freq`, change wlan0 to your wireless interface name.

Comment: Done. I have added the info at the end.

Comment: Your's is also wlan0?

Comment: Oops. Corrected. Sorry.

Comment: Let me put together an answer for you. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Give me just a minute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the router's admin page. Go to the wireless tab. Find the 5ghz settings. Change the channel to one of the following... higher channels are better...

```
      Channel 32 : 5.16 GHz
      Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
      Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
      Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
      Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
      Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
      Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
      Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
      Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
      Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
      Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
      Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
      Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
      Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
      Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
      Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
      Channel 66 : 5.33 GHz
      Channel 68 : 5.34 GHz
      Channel 96 : 5.48 GHz
```

Retry your PC.

Comment: It did work in channel 36. Curiously, the higher ones did not work. Thanks! What was the problem exactly?

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent  When you reset the router, it changed the 5ghz band back to a channel that your PC can't receive. Channel 64 should have worked. Try other higher channels, as they work better than the lower channels.

Comment: Nope, the highest channel that has succeeded is 48. All the others give me nothing...

Comment: You must be in Europe, yes? So the wireless card is fibbing about what channels it can REALLY connect to. But, we fixed it. Stick with 48 then.

Comment: Yes, Germany. Thanks a lot! I did not know that in Europe we were doing weird stuff with the channels.

Comment: Have a good day sir!